# MySQL - Split two columns into two different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I don't have any idea to create this sorry if it is a silly question.

I have a table two teams and total watch and I will use this information later a different place so my idea concat this two column in one column but two different rows:

```
HomeTeam      AwayTeam     Totalwatch 
A              B              100
A              C               90
C              A               80
D              B               70
C              E               50
```

Can I this

```
Teams          TotalWatch
A                100
B                100
A                 90
C                 90
C                 80
A                 80
D                 70
B                 70
C                 50
E                 50
```

I have a few columns so they will repeat as well.

Just a note I know how can `concat` in one-row use with `concat` function I do not know how can I make with two rows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` and an `ORDER BY Totalwatch DESC` to get the results ordered according to `Totalwatch`.

```
SELECT HomeTeam AS Teams, Totalwatch  FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT AwayTeam, Totalwatch FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Totalwatch DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT HomeTeam Teams,TotalWatch FROM Your_Table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AwayTeam,TotalWatch FROM Your_Table
    )D
ORDER BY TotalWatch DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this bro.. :)

```
SELECT HomeTeam,Totalwatch
FROM   YourTable

UNION ALL

SELECT AwayTeam,Totalwatch
FROM   YourTable
```